# How to shrink font size automatically in html table cell

Tags: html, html-table, overflow

How does one allow font size inside a table cell to shrink automatically whenever text overflows? Currently, the table cell just expands itself whenever text overflows.

Comment: Hey did you find the solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

You could set an overflow or use CCS media queries to dynamically change the font size.

Overflow:

```
 .your-class{overflow:auto;}
```

That would only show the scroll bar when the data gets bigger than the size of the cell.

CSS Media queries:

```
.your-class{
    font-size: 18px;
}

@media all and (max-device-width: 720px){
     .your-class {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

@media all and (max-device-width: 640px){
     .your-class {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

@media all and (max-device-width: 320px){
     .your-class {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}
```

The above changes the font size according to the view width of the device currently viewing the page.

Comment: Thanks. However, this is for a printout.